# How to select records in a table (in mysql) with a particular month (the month can be known from datetimepicker in visual studio)

Tags: c#, mysql, select, datagridview

My datagridview is not showing any records.
What im trying to do :- i want to get the records only for that department and that month which are filled in the combobox and datetimepicker respectively.

my database table is in mysql and im coding in c# in visual studio.
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from employee.transaction where department = '" + this.department.Text + "' and MONTHNAME(date) = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString() + "';", conDataBase);
```

try block is just some extra information if it helps i think the problem is in the select query.

```
            try
            {
               MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("New_DataTable");
                dt.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

               // string sql = "select * from employee.transaction where department = '" + this.department.Text + "' and month = '" + month + "';"; 

                ds.Tables.Add(dbdataset);
                //string filename = excel_name.Text;
                // filename = filename + .xls;
                ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", ds);
            }

MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from employee.transaction where department = '" + this.department.Text + "' and MONTHNAME(date) = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString() + "';", conDataBase);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try replacing your query with simple select like `Select * from employee.transaction ` and see if returns anything. This way you can check whether problem is with query?

Comment: Can you post the full code as well?  What method are you doing this in?  Where are you creating the MySqlCommand? Where is the SqlConnection instantiation?

Comment: Are you sure ˇMONTHNAMEˇ and ˇMonth.ToString()ˇ encode months the same way?

Comment: select * from employee.transaction returns the table (i.e. it works properly). how to check if MONTHNAME and Month.ToString are encoding in the same way or not i think the problem lies there itself.Thanks for the replies.